# Moving to Azure

Tags: .net, azure

I have a website which i wrote in .net and being hosted by some hosting company, I want to move to windows azure. Does anyone know how to move the app to Azure. Does it require code change to do that?

I have data in sqlserver which is also hosted by the same hosting company. This app was written 5 years back using asp.net. Yes, I need to move both data and aspx pages. I have the code in visual studio.

Comment: They give you a publish profile to download, and you publish it. Of course you also probably need to move your data too.

Comment: There are various questions before you can really answer that. Do you need the scalability of cloud services or the simplicity of Azure web sites? Where is your data and will that be moved? Do you have the original source code in Visual Studio or does someone else have the source. In general, you will not need to change it but there are certain patterns which are different in the cloud such as the way configuration and certificates work.

Comment: Lukos: I have data in sqlserver which is also hosted by the same hosting company. This app was written 5 years back using asp.net. Yes, I need to move both data and aspx pages. I have the code in visual studio.

Comment: Who knows?  How about this--publish to azure and see what happens.  If it doesn't work, ask a question about that.

Answer (score 2):

One of the key questions is whether Azure is necessary for your site, otherwise it can be expensive compared to more traditional hosting (but by all means check it out).

Things like high availability, automatic scaling, easy deployment from Visual Studio and online storage backed by CDN are all very useful for high-traffic sites but for things that are more simple, I would suggest that traditional hosting is more cost-effective.

For instance, as Thiago said, you can combine functionality on a single server very easily with traditional hosting (web server, storage and database) which is cheaper than a cloud service, SQL Azure instance and storage account but it depends whether you want the cloud functionality, need loads of bandwidth/space/performance or just want to leave your current provider and find something better/cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Lukos said, you can migrate your sql server to sql database (on azure), but there some features that Sql Database doesn't support, like stored procedures for example.

You can migrate your DB using SQL Database Migration Wizard: http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

or you can create a VM with Sql Server installed and point your Azure Web Site app to this new DB.

more info:

General Guidelines and Limitations (Windows Azure SQL Database)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx

Comparison of SQL Server with Windows Azure SQL Database

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/996.comparison-of-sql-server-with-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Azure has several plan for deploying the website. I think you can use the Azure Web Sites and SQL Azure for your purpose. No need code changes.

The deployment is very simple. You can deploy directly from source control (TFS) if you have or you create deployment package using visual studio.

Once you create the web role the DB automatically created. You should have the connection string so you can connect to SQL Azure with SSMS. Do SQL Compare using RedGate or something so that your DB have same schema and data with the existing.

There is some point that you should know that the SQL Azure only guarantee about 500 IOPS because it kind like shared MSSQL DB. If you really ok with this number, it should be fine. But if you need a fast DB such as intensive transaction data you should upgrade the default plan so you can get more IOPS (this can be digging your pocket deeper).

If you want to use VM, you need to configure each VM, load balance, security, vpn access, port forwarding, availability set, etc. It is complicated but the problem is same. You only have 500 IOPS to read and write to the disk. You should do some disk stripping so that you can have more IOPS then you can have faster disk R/W (use 4, 8, 12, 16 disk). Don't forget to warm up your disk too.

Last thing, with VM deployment, you need to make you system High Available. Azure won't guarantee your system to meet with their SLA if you don't have HA system.

Answer (score 0):

in your scenario you can possibly think about moving to azure virtual machines.
You can choose azure sql vm and just need to move the code as it is to IIS in vm as
well as database backup to vm sql.
Advantages:
You will not need any code changes for your code to work in azure vm.
If you go for sql azure,then your database has to be compatible with sql azure.
If you use sql in vm then no db changes are needed hence you can move seamlessly to azure

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options either to publish the app as an azure website which is easier and provide more support for the website or create a new virtual machine and follow the steps on how to publish a website on the IIS in which you will need SQL Server installed of course for your Database.

Hope This Helps